# How to wirte a Custom JaxB Class Binding for Class Name Conflicts

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

While I am trying to generate a stub classes for a web service, it generated  2 inner class with the same name "Catestrophe"

```
<com23:Catestrophe>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <com23:Entry>
        <!--Optional:-->
        -<com23:catastrophe>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <com23:Code>?</com23:Code>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <com23:Name>?</com23:Name>
        </com23:catastrophe>
    </com23:Entry>
</com23:catastrophe>
```

How to avoid this using custom JAXB Binding ?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/error-two-declarations-cause-a-collision-in-the-objectfactory-class